# java.home property adds extra slashes when it it written to a property file?

Tags: java, ant, backslash

As per my understanding, *java.home* is a ANT built-in property. In our scenerio, we write the value of *java.home*  to a another property file in the same project . Hovewer, we observed that when we write the value of *java.home*  to the aforesaid property file, the value is written with additional slashes(e.g: **‘d:/jdk1.6.0_12’ value is written to aforesaid property file as ‘d\:\\jdk1.6.0_12\\jre’**) and these additional slashes are causing issues in our system.

So, I need your suggestion/help/input to know 1) if there is a way to write *java.home* to another property file without additional slashes OR 2)if there is a way to write script in ANT build file such that when *java.home*  property will be read from aforesaid property file which containss additional slashes, the script will chop-off unwanted/additional slashes and will return the exact path to *java.home* .

Answer (score 3):

In a property-file, the `\` is an escape-character, which is used to escape all characters which have special meanings in the property-file-syntax, like a `:` here. It should be stripped of when reading the property file. Isn't it?

For exporting the value, maybe a simple `<echo file="...">${java.home}</echo>` instead of the property-file-export would be more useful?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: Your answer is theoratically correct however in our case we need to write the value of java.home to a property file which will be read again from the property file for the purpose of finding and replacing the tokens. So, I am still looking for the exact answer to my question.

Comment: and your finding/replacing does not work because of the backslashes?

Comment: No. If I take the approach suggested by you then it is ommitting the slashes completely giving the wrong results. **<echo file="${installation.properties.file}">jdk.home=${java.home}</echo> ** With above line of code the property is stored in property file as jdk.home=d:\jdk1.6.0_12\jre** . Now, when I am finding occurances of jdk.home and replacing the tokens with it's value it is replacing the tokens with **d:jdk1.6.0_12jre** (please note the absense of slash here) which is not correct.

Comment: @suhail_zone : You are chasing the wrong problem. The doubled slashes are a necessary part of the property file format. There is no way to have a slash in the file without escaping it. It is doubled on write and un-doubled on read. You don't have do anything special. Any comparison problems you are having are unrelated to the doubling of slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to this problem:

```
<path id="property.toreplace.path">
    <pathelement path="${property.toreplace}"/>
</path>
<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="formatted.property.toreplace" refid="property.toreplace.path"/>
```